# windows upgradation from windows 8 pro to windows 8.1

Tags: windows-8, windows-8.1-upgrade

My windows is not being upgraded from windows 8 pro to windows 8.1.It gives an error,"Sorry,this update isn't available for you pc or you might be running an edition of windows that does not support updating from the store". kindly help,how can I upgrade it?

Comment: Do you have all required updates installed currently?

Comment: @ramhound.yes,I have installed already.

Comment: You are trying to install the update through the Windows Store correct?

Comment: yes. windows itself asked to upgrade to 8.1,but when I pressed upgrade button it gives error as mentioned above.

Comment: What Language Packs do you have installed?  What region is your Windows Store set to?  Is the region its set to the **exact** same language as the primary license?  For instance if you have the English version of Windows 8 installed the upgrade will fail if you attempt to install the French version of Windows 8.1.  Please update your question to reflect all your responses from your comments.

Comment: Are you perhaps using an MSDN/TechNet key? Or some other volume licensing scheme?

Comment: TechNet key,,,,

Comment: language pack installed is English(US) and also store region is US.

Comment: @ramhound ,when I goes to PC setting->Personalize-> I see Lock screen,Account Picture and start screen options are hidden.They are not working.

Comment: Do you use a Windows VL edition (MAK key or KMS)? Both can't be upgraded via Store. You need to upgrade them via DVD and setup.exe->Upgrade.

Answer (score 1):

TechNet versions of Windows 8 have the same restrictions to updating as Volume License versions. Please see the section titled 'You might be running an edition of Windows 8 that doesn’t support updating from the Store' in [this Microsoft article](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-8/why-can-t-find-update-store#). The same process that magicandre1981 mentioned is required... Download the 8.1 ISO from TechNet and run 'setup.exe /auto:upgrade'.

Hope this helps,

Comment: I also underwent similar issues and most time the 8.1 ISO solved my problem.